# Deploy Delphi XE7 app with XCode 6.0.1 (6A317), on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

I tried to deploy very simple app made with Delphi XE7 on iOS simulator. Version of XCode is now 6.0.1, with Command Line tools updated as well. I tried to start this app in simulator with simulators 8.0 and 7.1. with appropriate SDK versions.

App is installed and can be seen on iOS simulator, but when I start it, after a second app closes itself without any message. in .crash file in log there is an error listed -

missing LC_DYLD_INFO load command.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: As XE7 was released before iOS 8 there is a chance that it is not compatible. As usual a few days after the iOS release we expect an update or hotfix to raise it to the new iOS level.

Comment: Probably.., but I tried to downgrade SDK to 7.1 as well. Still the same error. So, the next step would be to go back to Delphi XE6 as well, as it worked well.

Comment: People have XE7 and IOS8 working over on the Embarcadero forum. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108372&tstart=15

Comment: Finally, I tried the app on device and it worked perfectly. Than I started much more complex app and it worked perfectly again.

So, my experience is - there are issues with Simulators, but no issues with devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues with simulators as such.

XE7 does not work with Xcode 6 (yet) - hopefully there will be an update soon which will allow for this.

You can however install both Xcode 5 and 6 on your mac simultaneously.

To test with iOS 8 you will need to deploy directly to the device until Xcode 6 support is added.

Answer (score 0):

I has upload my IOS8 app to app store today build with Delphi XE7 and Xcode 6.0.1
I compiled and remove this lines from Info.plist before I deployed the app

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
<string>12A365</string>
<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
<string>6A317</string>
```

/Magnus Westlund